# phantomjs to render a page from a string

Tags: phantomjs, headless-browser

I want to render a webpage from a string. I've looked at the docs of phantomjs and they suggested the following:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var expectedContent = '<html><body><div>Test div</div></body></html>';
var expectedLocation = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
page.setContent(expectedContent, expectedLocation);
```

It's not quite working. Why? (I use the latest version).

Comment: I don't see how you verify how it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you render a normal page (`about:blank` works)  and then do `webPage.content='<html><body><div>Test div</div></body></html>';`

then render your page.

hope that helps.